# ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control. c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

In my form I have datagrid view and I select the data into datagridview by using the following
stored procedure :

```
create proc [dbo].[GET_CULTURE_RESULT_DETAILS]
@ORDER_ID int 
as 
select LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.[organism_id] as 'Org.Id' , organism_desc as 'Organism Name'
      ,LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.[Antibiotic_id] as 'Ant.Id', Antibiotic_Name as 'Antibiotic Name'
      ,LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.[sensitivityId] as 'Sens.Id', Sensitivity_desc as 'Sensitivity Name'
from LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS 
inner join lab_organisms on LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.organism_id = lab_organisms.organism_id
inner join lab_antibiotics on LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.Antibiotic_id = lab_antibiotics.Antibiotic_id
inner join Lab_Sensitivity on LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.sensitivityId = Lab_Sensitivity.sensitivityId

where LAB_MICRO_RESULTS_DETAILS.order_id = @ORDER_ID
```

Then when select the order number datagridview filled using key down event this is the code :

```
private void txtOrder_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter && txtOrder.Text != string.Empty)

            {
                dgvcultures.DataSource = micro.GET_CULTURE_RESULT_DETAILS(Convert.ToInt32(txtOrder.Text));
                txtPCfile.Focus();
            }
        }
```

Finally the error appeared when I try to add new row into the datagrid view by using this code :

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
                    if (dgvcultures.Columns.Count >= 0)
                    {
               
                        dgvcultures.ColumnCount = 6;
                        dgvcultures.Columns[0].Name = "Org.Id";
                        dgvcultures.Columns[1].Name = "Organism Name";
                        dgvcultures.Columns[2].Name = "Ant.Id";
                        dgvcultures.Columns[3].Name = "Antibiotic Name";
                        dgvcultures.Columns[4].Name = "Sens.Id";
                        dgvcultures.Columns[5].Name = "Sensitivity Name";



                        dgvcultures.Rows.Add(comboOrganism.SelectedValue.ToString(), comboOrganism.Text,
                            comboAntibiotics.SelectedValue.ToString(), comboAntibiotics.Text,
                            comboSensitivity.SelectedValue.ToString(), comboSensitivity.Text);
                        // comboGrowth.SelectedValue.ToString(),comboGrowth.Text);

                    }
     }
```

when click add button and try to insert new row I got this error :

```
ColumnCount property cannot be set on a data-bound DataGridView control. c#
```

I checked the solutions in this site and they said you have to clear the datagridview before insert new rows I tried it its clear the filled data from stored procedure and I dont need to clear datagridview , I need to keep the data and add new rows without clear the current data :

```
//Clear the binding.
dgvcultures.DataSource = null;
```

this command will remove the rows in datagridview , but I need to keep rows.

How to solve this error please.

Comment: Add the new row to the grids `DataSource`. As the error clearly states you can NOT directly ADD rows into the "GRID" when it has a `DataSource`... data-bound..

Comment: @JohnG how to save the rows in datasource and append new rows to that datasource without clear the available rows ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can decipher, the grids `DataSource` looks like a `DataTable` with the following columns…

Org.Id, Organism Name, Ant.Id, Antibiotic Name, Sens.Id and Sensitivity Name.

I assume this from the first snippet of code that gets the table from the DB.

If this `DataTable` is used as a `DataSource` to the grid, then in the button click event, it is unnecessary to “re-create” the columns. Those columns already exist in the table. The code simply needs to add the row to the `DataTable.` It is not clear if the column “types” are all `strings` and the code may have to convert some values, otherwise the code in the button click event may look something like…

```
DataTable gridDT = (DataTable)dgvcultures.DataSource;
gridDT.Rows.Add(comboOrganism.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                comboOrganism.Text,
                comboAntibiotics.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                comboAntibiotics.Text,
                comboSensitivity.SelectedValue.ToString(),
                comboSensitivity.Text);
```

Lastly, you should consider using a `BindingSource`. It may make things easier.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: the error appeared in this line in the loop  dgvcultures.ColumnCount = 6; can you post the complete code for the void private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) thanks in advance

Comment: Remove that line of code it is not needed. The Grid\Table already has 6 columns.